# Should I have my Postgres directory right next to my project folder? If so, how?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to develop a Django website with Heroku. Having no previous experience with databases (except the sqlite3 one from the tutorial), it seems to me a good idea to have the following file structure:

```
Projects
'-MySite
  |-MySite
  '-MyDB
```

I'm finding it hard to figure out how to do it, with `psql` commands preferring to put the databases in some obscure directory instead. Perhaps it's not such a good idea?

Eventually I want to be able to test and develop my site  (it'll be just a blog for a while, I'm still learning) locally (ie. add a post, play with the CSS) and sync with the Heroku repository, but I also want to be able to add posts via the website itself occasionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying data files (MyDb) has nothing to do with your project files and should *not* be under your project.

**EDIT**
added two ways to sync your local database with the database ON the Heroku server

1) export-import

This is the most simple way, do the following steps every now and then:

- make an *export* on the Heroku server by using the [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) utility
- download the dump file
- *import* the dump into your local database by using the [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) utility

2) replication

A more sophisticated way for keeping your local db in sync all the time is *Replication*. It is used in professional environments and it is probably an overkill for you at the moment. You can read more about it here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/high-availability.html

Comment: Could you explain a bit why, or point me towards a resource? I was using a GUI to navigate my first sqlite3 database and it seemed like it was very much "owned" by the project, so it made sense having it in the project directory (though .gitignore'd).

Comment: So, to clarify, I would NOT be uploading the database to Heroku at any point. I would just want to keep the one in Heroku identical to the one in my laptop at all times.

The fact that nobody seems to have instructions to do this suggests that it's not a good idea, but finding info about WHY it is bad and what to do instead is pretty difficult too.

Comment: I see. The sqlite is different story, because in that case the whole database is just one file. When using PostgreSQL or MySQL or similar databases it is somewhat more complicated to sync databases then copying a file. See my edit